# How to check the progress of mkfs.vfat in a C program?

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing a utility tool as a part of a Qt application.

Basically, I'm trying to run`system("mkfs.vfat /dev/mmcblk0 -c -n NAME");` when a button is pressed.

Problem is, with `-c` option, this call takes a long time to run, approximately 20 minutes, so it'll be good to display a progress bar in the app to tell the user that the app is not dead: it's just slow.

I googled for a while, but only found a few feature requests for adding progress check to `mkfs`.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: `mkfs.vfat -v ...` for verbose execution? Not sure if that does anything useful in the bad-block scan, though...

Comment: @twalberg Nice idea. Instead of using `system()`, I can use `popen` and then parse the output of `-v`. Not a graceful solution but a promising workaround!